# Why or How does setTimeout run once when called directly but run in a loop when called from within a function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This question is related to [SetTimeout is confusing me and I need to be able to promisify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013223/settimeout-is-confusing-me-and-i-need-to-be-able-to-promisify-it) as I am trying to understand the basics of setTimeout.

When I call setTimeout as below (directly from outside) it runs just once and this is clear to me as it's what the definition of setTimeout says

*A function to be executed after the timer expires.*

```
let i = 0;
let str = "Alim";

function type() {
  console.log(str, str.length, i);
}
type(); // runs immediately

setTimeout(type, 3000); // runs after 3 secs
```

But when I call it from within a function (or as some say - call it from within itself) then it runs in a loop every 3 secs.. but why and how? I can't get my head around this and trying more complex stuff without understanding the basics might not be a good idea for me..

Why does the setTimeout run again and again in the code below when it's actually called just once from outside by typing `type()`

```
let i = 0;
let str = "Alim";

function type() {
  console.log(str, str.length, i); // runs immediately
  setTimeout(type, 3000); // runs after 3 secs and again and again and again.....!!!
}
type();
```

Comment: Do you understand what happens if you call `type()` directly inside the `type` function (instead of `setTimeout(type, 3000)`)? Have you heard of recursion?

Comment: it is not `A function to be executed after the timer expires.` but `A function to be executed after the delay expires.` setTimeout is not a chronometric function...

Comment: Let's start simple: what do you think will happen when you call `setTimeout(type, 3000); setTimeout(type, 6000);` (without calling setTimeout inside again)?

Comment: It is *not* "called just once from outside", the code passes the `type()` function to `setTimeout()` so it will be re-started.

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't see a useful distinction between a "timer" and a "delay". A timer expires after a delay.

Comment: Also, I'm really not sure how not to get this; the setTimeout line causes type to run 3 seconds from now, and when type runs, it calls the setTimeout line again, which causes type to run 3 seconds from now, which calls the setTimeout line again, which makes type run again 3 seconds from now, and so on, and so on. It's exactly like scheduling your next appointment at the end of a visit to the dentist.

Comment: @ChrisG Nice metaphor!

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response.. Bergi : will definitely read up on recursion.. @ChrisG : Thanks for the dentist appointment analogy..:-).. that's when I really got i!..:-)..

Comment: @Bergi a `timer` can be used for mesuring time, a `delay` can't, 5s delay can be more than 5s

Comment: @MisterJojo Who says that `setTimeout` doesn't create a timer internally? The browser will indeed measure the time to know when the timer expires. The term "timer" is used synonymously to "timeout" here.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so, and the MDN documentation uses the term delay, not timer. otherwise there are some topics here dealing with the lack of precision of setTimeout() and even setInterval()

Comment: (@ MisterJojo and Bergi) Just to help you guys sort it out.. I did pick up the 'timer' definition from the MDN site.. so MDN says 'timer'.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout